# Run Private Browsing Mode and Normal Session simultaneously in Firefox

Tags: firefox

If I start private browsing, Firefox quits normal Firefox instance and switches to Private browsing.

So is there any way to stop firefox from starting private browsing without closing the normal Firefox instance running?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to do this.  However, Chrome/Chromium does this by default, so if this behavior is vital, you could try out Chrome...

Comment: @adempewolff Yeah i know chrome can do this but i actually use firefox as my first browser . so i want that feature in firefox . Thank you :)

Comment: This is an old thread. I just wanted to give a heads up that now (2018) default behaviour allows both private and normal sessions to run simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the way Private Browsing works by default is that it closes all tabs, saves them & switches to Private Browsing mode. An alternative would be to create a new profile & launch Firefox with that profile and switch to private browsing mode in that profile. That way, you can have both windows.

There used to an [add-on which made](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/private-browsing-window/) both normal & private browsing possible, but this addon has been disabled now.

FWIW There's a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=463027) on this, you can follow it if you like.

Comment: @Satya , Thanks for the info brother .i will wait some more time .